# What is the proper, mathematically rigorous way to notate intervals with units?

Tags: notation, unit-of-measure, interval-arithmetic

I would like to notate something to the effect of the following—

> $$\left\{ x \ \mathrm{cm}\,\middle|\,0\lt x\le5\right\}$$

—but as an interval.

Here’s what’s in my mind:

$$\begin{array}{cl}
\text{(1)} & (0,5] \ \mathrm{cm} \\
\text{(2)} & (0 \ \mathrm{cm} ,5 \ \mathrm{cm}] \\
\text{(3)} & \text{doesn’t really work} \\
\end{array}$$

$\text{(1)}$ seems less than rigorous, because it’s multiplying an interval by an entity, and that just seems weird. $\text{(2)}$ is clear, but it doesn’t seem sound, because the real line doesn’t include units. Is $\text{(3)}$ my only option?

And as an extra twist, consider

> $$\left\{ x \ \mathrm{cm}\,\middle|\,0\lt x\lt\infty\right\}$$

Comment: If you insist on clearly differentiating 5 cm from the real number 5 then the objection "the real line doesn’t include units" isn't really relevant.

Comment: @ProjectBook Interesting… Could you elaborate?

Comment: (1) doesn't seem weird to me, because there is a well-defined operation of multiplication of lengths (such as the centimetre) by positive real numbers. Extending the operation to intervals is OK, at least if you explain what notation you are using. (2) is even clearer, because, in whatever way "lengths" may be defined, they are going to form a totally ordered set (in theory at least, although in practice it might be hard to define an equivalence relation of "exactly equal length"), and intervals are defined in any ordered set. It's just that measurement is a topic not often treated rigorously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many years later, I have done enough reading to come to know that none of these are used at all.

The [SI brochure](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/) says to label axes and tables with “the ratio of a quantity to its unit.”  Axes represent intervals.  Therefore, the common practice would be $$x/\mathrm{cm}\in(0,5]$$

Answer (score 0):

(1) seems fine, and (2) is okay too.   They indicate the interval and the units of measurement used over it.

$$(0;5]\mathrm{cm} ~{=~ (0\mathrm{cm};5\mathrm{cm}] \\=~ \{s\mid 0\mathrm{cm}\lt s\leqslant 5\mathrm{cm}\} \\=~ \{x\cdotp\mathrm{cm}\mid 0<x\leqslant 5\}}$$